It does not violate copyrights to design/use a generic 3D soccer ball and 3D basket ball (without brand name or logo) for commercial games. True?
I am developing a 3D commercial game. My artist creates a 3D soccer ball and a 3D basket ball with a generic design. The 3D soccer ball and the 3D basket ball do not have any brand name or logo of any companies or sport organizations such as Nike, Adidas, FIFA, etc...
So, I should not have to worry about violating any design or copyright materials for this soccer ball and basket ball anywhere in the world. Is it true ?
For reference, I am in the US.



"with a generic design": the soccer ball design shown here was developed in the 1960s and could be protected.  The basketball design could also be protected, though it seems less likely as it is (I think) somewhat older.  I have a feeling it's from the 1940s or '50s, but I couldn't confirm that.

Of course you can use generic balls in a video game, just as one can a myriad of other generic buildings, crates, guns, or other items.
The generic design of these balls is (at least somewhat) functional and cannot be copyrighted. Functional designs can be patented, but even if it were, a depiction would not violate the patent.
If you were to put brand names on them, you'd be dealing with trademark law, rather than copyright, involving the question of whether using trademarks comprises an implicit endorsement. Normally, not, but just to be safe, video games usually change the brand's name a bit.
The one scenario where you'd deal with copyrights is e.g. depicting a very fancy custom ball or a designer tattoo. 7 years later, the case about designer tattoos came to a verdict that they were legal to depict in that instance.
What one has to worry about is not using copyrighted images for textures. So it's best to either check that they're under a free license, or take the required photos personally, or license them, or draw them in design software.
